# pass parameter to apex from lwc doinit

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, js

I am trying to pass parameter on page load in LWC. Is this correct way of passing parameter to apex?

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import CurrentUserId from '@salesforce/user/Id';
import setData from '@salesforce/apex/myClass.setData';
export default class myClasstest extends LightningElement {
    connectedCallback(){
        console.log('CurrentUserId '+CurrentUserId);
        setData(CurrentUserId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand calling apex method imperatively in LWC. A sample method is below. Here, **searchKey** is the parameter name defined in apex. The imported function returns a promise. If your method returns any value, **result** has that value. if there is any error, it will go in catch block.

```
   connectedCallback() {
        findContacts({ searchKey: this.value })
            .then((result) => {
                this.contacts = result;
                this.error = undefined;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.error = error;
                this.contacts = undefined;
            });
    }
```

Read more here:- [Call Apex Methods Imperatively](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex_call_imperative)

Also, check out lwc recipes examples here:-

1. [apexImperativeMethod](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/apexImperativeMethod)
2. [apexImperativeMethodWithComplexParams](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/apexImperativeMethodWithComplexParams)
3. [apexImperativeMethodWithParams](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/apexImperativeMethodWithParams)